# error in the volume calculater execution

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, volume

I started with a basic package checker that checks for your package details and checks if it matches with the rules I have created. I am having a difficulty with executing the volume calculation in this program. Basically, what I want to create is a program that gets the user input on his package length, width and height, then multiply those and divide by 100 to get the volume in cubic meters. I don't know how to execute the calculating part of my program.

Here's my code:

```
public class PackageCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double weight = 0;
        double length = 0;
        double width = 0;
        double height = 0; 

        System.out.println("||Please enter your package details||");
        java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your package weight in kg");
        weight=input.nextDouble();
        if (weight > 27) {
            System.out.println("Package is too heavy!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter your package length");
            length=input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter your package width");
            width=input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter your package height");
            height=input.nextDouble();
        }
        double volume = length * width * height  / 100;
        if (volume > 0.1 && weight < 27) {
            System.out.println("Package is too large!");
        }
        input.close(); //this ends the user input console    
    }
}
```

Comment: programming is executing but the volume calculation is missing.

Comment: where volume is missing??

Comment: double volume = length * width * height  / 100;
        if (volume > 0.1 && weight < 27) {
            System.out.println("Package is too large!");

Comment: please clearly explain your problem.As it is currently written, you are asking where to put this line `double volume = length * width * height  / 100;`and the answer is: exactly where you wrote it.

Comment: Maybe using a debugger could help you

Comment: I guess the problem is that you have to read the text noted by pressing the Enter key. You have to use `Scanner#nextLine` after each call to `input#nextDouble`.

Comment: yes i understand that but the program is not taking the that calculation and its suppose to give the users a  input after they entered all of the info about their package.

Comment: Simple way for you to debug this yourself: At the line where you set `double volume`, call a bunch of `println`s on all of the variables to see if they all match what you expect them to match. If they don't, then figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the character(s) written in the input stream entered from user when he/she pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. You can do this by using `Scanner#nextLine`.

Here's an example of how this should be done:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your package weight in kg");
weight=input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine(); //consumes the \n or \r\n
```

You have to do this after reading each user input that contains an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For your case, seems that you have to add this line after every `input.nextDouble`.

Comment: Thanks alot homie, thats just what i was looking for.